# Need apache rewrite rule assist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to add some rewrite rules to a website.

Here's the idea =>

Rewrite all non-subdomain traffic from

```
(http or https)://(www. or no www.)example.com/whatever
(http or https)://www.example.com/whatever
```

(so basically, always force www.)

**Also** rewrite only this 1 sumbdomain =>

```
(http or https)://(www. or no www.)store.example.com/whatever
(http or https)://www.example.com/whatever
```

Keep all other subdomains intact.

So far I have this =>

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%{ENV:askapache}://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it's not working as expected...

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:store\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input but I'm getting a "This webpage has a redirect loop" error http://store.example.com/httpstore.://www.example.com....

Comment: How could that be since redirected URI has host www.example.com` and that will make this condition fail: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(store\.)?example\.com$ [NC]`. Do you have some other stuff in .htaccess also?

Comment: I made some minor change, can you pls try edited code now?

Comment: WOW! seems to work so far.. I'll test it a bit more and accept your answer if everything is ok.. thanks a lot!!!!!!

Comment: everything seems to be working properly.. thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out.